# How to control the end of line delimiter when reading csv

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a csv file with delimiter "|" by using the python language. When I read the csv file through the below code, the delimiter is not splitted well. Is there any option in order to control the end of line delimiter in csv?

```
import csv

csv = r"//path/test.csv"

with open(csv) as csv:
 csvRead=csv.DictReader(csv, delimiter='|')
 for row in csvRead:
   print(row)
```

Example

**What I expect to see:**

[image]

**What the result looks like:**

[image]

Could you please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should also show what you really have in file. And put it as text, not images.

Comment: you defined `delimiter` between columns but you didn't change delimiter between rows -  `end of line` - which split data into rows. So it automatically creates new row when it sees `\n`. But I'm wondering how you recognize end of row in your file - or maybe you have only one row in file.

Comment: you use the same variable `csv` for path and opened file - but this makes conflict with name of module `csv` - you should use different names for variables.